# Timeout not reflect for ElementFinder: (xpath, css)

Tags: selenium, testing, promise, protractor

Team, I have a function, which needs to locate the element,

```
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var busyLoaderEC = EC.stalenessOf(busyLoaderElement);
    var eleClickPresenceEC = EC.presenceOf(eleClickObject);
    var eleClickableEC = EC.elementToBeClickable(eleClickObject);

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    try {
        browser.wait(EC.and(busyLoaderEC, eleClickPresenceEC, eleClickableEC),
            config.timeout, constants.errorMessages.conditionTimedOut).then(function () {

                browser.sleep(1000); //Force Delay                    
                commonHelper.highlightElement(eleClickObject);



            }, function (error) {
                commonHelper.writeLog("ClickObject: " + error);
                deferred.reject(["ClickObject: " + error, reportFiller]);
            });
    }
    catch (error) {
        deferred.reject(["ClickObject: Element Not found -" + error, reportFiller]);
    }
```

When there element is an **id** and it expected to be not found, it will wait for the `config.timeout` finished then return an error with the error message as I defined in `constants.errorMessages.conditionTimedOut`.

But for CSS, or xpath locator,  if this element could not be found, there is no timeout, it will immediately throw following error:

```
CT-Driver Automation Suite Iteration   Message:
    Failed: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //div[@wj-part='root']//div[@wj-part='cells']//div[4]//span)   Stack:
    NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //div[@wj-part='root']//div[@wj-part='cells']//div[4]//span)
        at WebDriverError (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:10)
        at NoSuchElementError (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:242:10)
        at c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:699:27
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27
        at c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)    From: Task: WebDriver.executeScript()
        at Driver.schedule (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:377:17)
        at Driver.executeScript (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:526:16)
        at Browser.to.(anonymous function) [as executeScript] (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:60:29)
        at Object.highlightElement (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\common\commonHelper.js:409:24)
        at c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\services\seleniumService.js:82:34
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27
        at c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
    From: Task: Run it("Suite Iteration") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:81:14)
        at c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:18:5
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27     From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\app.js:111:3)
        at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\*\Documents\projects\*\ct-driver\app.js:65:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

This is annoying since I want my testing case continue even it encountered the "element_not_found" error.

Could you help me regarding this?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

## ExepectedConditions calls ElementFinder.isPresent

When you call `ExpectedConditions`, it appears that `stalenessOf` makes a call to `presenceOf`. `presenceOf` calls the `ElementFinder.isPresent` method and if you look at the [`isPresent` method](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/element.ts#L434):

```
/**
 * Returns true if there are any elements present that match the finder.
 *
 * @alias element.all(locator).isPresent()
 *
 * @example
 * expect($('.item').isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
 *
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
 */
isPresent(): wdpromise.Promise<boolean> {
  return this.count().then((count) => {
    return count > 0;
  });
}
```

## Immediate evaluation of ExpectedConditions

As soon as you call these EC methods, they are thrown on the control flow and evaluated. So when you initialize these values at the top:

```
var busyLoaderEC = EC.stalenessOf(busyLoaderElement);
var eleClickPresenceEC = EC.presenceOf(eleClickObject);
var eleClickableEC = EC.elementToBeClickable(eleClickObject);
```

you are immediately resolving these promises on the control flow. This means that when you call `browser.wait`, they should fail because no waiting period of `config.timeout` was allowed for these elements to appear on the screen, not be on the screen, or checked to be clickable.

So instead what should happen is:

```
browser.wait(EC.and(EC.stalenessOf(busyLoaderElement),
    EC.presenceOf(eleClickObject),
    EC.elementToBeClickable(eleClickObject)),
    config.timeout, constants.errorMessages.conditionTimedOut).then(() => {
```

Comment: Totally understand what you are saying but the strange thing is if the element I try to find is "ID" then it will wait for timeout, but not for "xpath" or "css". that`s a pretty strange behavior.

Comment: If you take my recommendations and you still cannot find your value, then potentially your `xpath` search is not correct. If you are on the latest Protractor you could send the command `protractor conf.js --highlightDelay 2000`. This allows you to see highlighted values that enter the control flow. See https://twitter.com/cnishina/status/826971080648642560 for an example